# Infinite Loop When Reading TFRecord file

Tags: python, tensorflow, eval, binaryfiles

I'm currently trying to read a TFRecord file but my terminal crashes whenever I try to evaluate the tensors I have just generated from the file data. I'm working with RNNs (recurrent neural networks) and so I am trying to do my work using sequence data. I've copied most of the code from [here](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/) but I have made my own additions to try and include a TFRecordReader.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tempfile
import os

sequences = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 1], [1, 2]]
label_sequences = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1]]

def make_example(sequence, labels):
    # The object we return
    ex = tf.train.SequenceExample()
    # A non-sequential feature of our example
    sequence_length = len(sequence)
    ex.context.feature["length"].int64_list.value.append(sequence_length)
    # Feature lists for the two sequential features of our example
    fl_tokens = ex.feature_lists.feature_list["tokens"]
    fl_labels = ex.feature_lists.feature_list["labels"]
    for token, label in zip(sequence, labels):
        fl_tokens.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(token)
        fl_labels.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(label)
    return ex

def parse_example(filename_queue):

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    print(example)

    #example = filename_queue

    context_features = {
    "length": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
    }
    sequence_features = {
        "tokens": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
        "labels": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
    }

    # Parse the example
    context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
        serialized=example,
        context_features=context_features,
        sequence_features=sequence_features
    )

    return context_parsed, sequence_parsed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generated_file = ""
    #################################
    # Write all examples into a TFRecords file
    #################################
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as fp:
        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(fp.name)
        generated_file = fp.name
        for sequence, label_sequence in zip(sequences, label_sequences):
            ex = make_example(sequence, label_sequence)
            writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
        writer.close()

    #################################
    # Read contents of TFRecord file
    #################################


    filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), generated_file)
    print(filename)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
        context_parsed, sequence_parsed = parse_example(filename_queue)
        print(context_parsed)
        print(sequence_parsed)

        # THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        # terminal freezes if the following lines are uncommented

        #print(context_parsed["length"].eval()) 
        #print(sequence_parsed["tokens"].eval()) 
        #print(sequence_parsed["labels"].eval())
```

I'm still getting familiar with tensorflow so I'd appreciate an explanation for what I'm doing wrong (not just code fixes) so I don't make a similar mistake in future. Thank You!

--

EDIT: Ok I've altered the above with the following:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess) # I included this line
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

But this is giving me the following error:

**ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Attempted to use a closed Session.**

I'm not sure what is wrong with this. Yaroslav's comments are correct according to the [directions on tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/) but I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I've tried several different formats of my code but I'm not sure what it is I'm missing.

--

EDIT2: Ok, I figured it out. Apparently I needed to generate a coordinator and pass that to the queue runners to get it to work. Here is my finalized code:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        context_parsed, sequence_parsed = parse_example(filename_queue)
        for i in range(3):
            v1,v2,v3 = sess.run([context_parsed["length"], sequence_parsed["tokens"], sequence_parsed["labels"]])
            print(v1,v2,v3)
```

Comment: you need to start queue runners